# Spring batch : JobScope not available in Spring 3.0.0

Tags: spring, maven, spring-batch

According to the Spring batch [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/), `JobScope` was introduced as part of Spring batch 3.0. However, it looks like the JobScope annotation is not available in Spring batch 3.0 jars. I have specified the `spring-batch-core` dependency in my `pom.xml` as follows :

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.batch.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I change the `spring-batch-version` to `3.0.6`, the `JobScope` annotation is found as expected. It was my understanding that `JobScope` was introduced as part of spring batch 3.0 and should therefore be availble in any spring batch jar starting from 3.0.0.

Is there any specific reason why `JobScope` annotation is not available in version 3.0.0 or do I manually need to add additional jars that contain this annotation? I believe the `spring-batch-core` dependency should pull all additional spring batch dependencies and I don't need to specify them explicitly.

I am using annotation based configuration to write batch jobs. I need the `JobScope` annotation for late-binding of job parameters to my beans. Is there a way to do this without using `JobScope`?

**Edit**

My job configuration file is as follows :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class FileLoaderConfigurationNoAbstractLoader {

    @Autowired
    private ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver;

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1) {
        return jobs.get("FileLoader").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(s1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public FlatFileItemReader reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filePath,
            @Value("#{jobParameters['fieldSetMapperClass']}") String fieldSetMapperClass,
            @Value("#{jobParameters['processType']}") String processType, @Value("#{jobParameters['dataType']}") String dataType,
            FileLoaderCreator loader) {
        String path = filePath.substring(filePath.indexOf(":") + 1, filePath.length());
        return loader.getReader(path, fieldSetMapperClass, processType, dataType);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "job", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public ItemWriter writer(@Value("#{jobParameters['dataType']}") String dataType) {
        return new CollectionItemWriter(dataType);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "job", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public ItemProcessor processor(FileLoaderCreator loader, @Value("#{jobParameters['itemProcessorClass']}") String itemProcessorClass) {
        return loader.getItemProcessor(itemProcessorClass);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "job", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public Step readStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader reader, ItemWriter writer, ItemProcessor processor,
            TaskExecutor taskExecutor, FileLoaderCreator fileLoader, @Value("#{jobParameters['dataType']}") String dataType,
            @Value("#{jobParameters['processType']}") String processType) {

        final Step readerStep = stepBuilderFactory.get(dataType + " ReadStep:slave")
                .chunk(fileLoader.getCommitInterval(processType, dataType)).reader(reader).processor(processor).writer(writer)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor).throttleLimit(fileLoader.getThrottleLimit(processType, dataType)).build();

        final Step partitionedStep = stepBuilderFactory.get(dataType + " ReadStep:master").partitioner(readerStep)
                .partitioner(dataType + " ReadStep:slave", partitioner(fileLoader, null, null)).taskExecutor(taskExecutor).build();

        return partitionedStep;

    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "job", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Partitioner partitioner(FileLoaderCreator fileLoader, @Value("#{jobParameters['processType']}") String processType,
            @Value("#{jobParameters['dataType']}") String dataType) {
        MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
        Resource[] resources;
        try {
            resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("file:" + fileLoader.getPath(processType, dataType)
                    + fileLoader.getFilePattern(processType, dataType));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("I/O problems when resolving the input file pattern.", e);
        }
        partitioner.setResources(resources);
        return partitioner;
    }

    /*
     * Use this if you want the writer to have job scope (JIRA BATCH-2269).
     * Might also change the return type of writer to ListItemWriter for this to
     * work.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor() {
            @Override
            protected void doExecute(final Runnable task) {
                // gets the jobExecution of the configuration thread
                final JobExecution jobExecution = JobSynchronizationManager.getContext().getJobExecution();
                super.doExecute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        JobSynchronizationManager.register(jobExecution);

                        try {
                            task.run();
                        } finally {
                            JobSynchronizationManager.close();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public FileLoaderCreator loader() {
        System.out.println("Creating loader only once ");
        return new FileLoaderCreator();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobResults jobResults() {
        return new JobResults();
    }
}
```

As per [M.Deinum's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) suggestion, I used `@Scope(value = "job", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` instead of the `JobScope` annotation but ran into the following exception :

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'job'' exception`

I tried fixing this by adding the following bean to the above configuration :

```
    @Bean
    public JobScope jobScope() {
        JobScope scope = new JobScope();
        scope.setAutoProxy(false);
        return scope;
    }
```

This gives me an exception at the following line in my java configuration :

```
resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("file:" + fileLoader.getPath(processType, dataType)
                + fileLoader.getFilePattern(processType, dataType));
```

Note that this works perfectly fine with `JobScope` and spring batch 3.0.1.

Comment: It was added in 3.0.1. But using `@JobScope` is the same as using `@Scope(value = "job", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`. But why not simply use 3.0.6 which is the most recent 3.0 release why stick with an older version?

Comment: @M.Deinum True. The lowest version containing this annotation seems to be 3.0.1. Does this mean that if I have to go with annotation based job configuration, I have no option but to use 3.0.1 or above? Our company has a framework approval process and current approved version of spring batch is 3.0.0.

Comment: See my edited comment...

Comment: @M.Deinum Our company has a framework approval process and current approved version of spring batch is 3.0.0. We would have to justify the requirement to use 3.0.1 instead of 3.0.0 and all projects would have to upgrade to this version. Let me try out your suggestion. If it works out, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'job'' exception` when I use spring batch 3.0.0 and spring 4.2.4. On further investigation, I found that there is a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2253) already raised for this issue which indicates that the fix is provided in 3.0.1. I tried creating a `JobScope` `Bean` as mentioned [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/116072-illegalstateexception-no-scope-registered-for-scope-job) but that did not resolve the issue either.

Comment: Make sure that the `JobScope` is registered properly and not as part of your job definition.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you elaborate more on this? I am posting my job configuration file for more info.

Comment: It has to be loaded BEFORE you are going to configure your job (i.e. it has to be part of your global batch configuration).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have posted the job configuration to make things more clear. Let me know if I have missed something.

Comment: I would create 2 classes one for enabling and configuring batch including the scope, the other for your job. However I would strongly suggest to upgrade to the most recent batch version, there is no reason to stick to 3.0.0. Also the bean for `JobScope` would have to be static, as it is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. Not sure why it isn't in the batch config.

Comment: @M.Deinum Let me tryout your suggestions again. Upgrading a thirdparty framework version is a lengthy process in my company. Once updated, all projects are bound to use the latest version so the upgrade needs to be justified as a showstopper.

Comment: I worked for those companies and ran ... Not really agile and it basically stops (or at least slows down) progress. Another solution don't use Java configuration use xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using annotation based configuration to write batch jobs. I need
>   the JobScope annotation for late-binding of job parameters to my
>   beans. Is there a way to do this without using JobScope?

it should work without Jobscope, by using Stepscope you can access the jobparameters, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope

if you need informations available for all beans you can implement a simple spring bean (type concurrent hashmap) which holds the informations

if you need the informations persisted for each batch run, you can implement a [JobExecutionListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html) which puts/pulls* the informations in JobExecutionContext and fills the (aforementioned) simple bean

*) if you need re-start

Comment: Thanks. My understanding of `StepScope` was that a new bean will be created for each execution of the step. Since I am using partitioning, I believe a new `Step` will be executed per partition. Consequently, there will be a new instance of each bean marked as `StepScope` per execution of the `Step`. Is this understanding correct? If yes, I would be creating way too many instances of an item writer and item processor (one per partition) even when one instance per job execution is what I really want. Also, Is storing large amount of data in a job context recommended?

Comment: right now i really cant imagine a stateless reader for x partitions (especially not for file resources), for processing/writing it is quite possible, again, except for file resources, in your example, it depends on "dataType" only which you could provide with the mentioned alternate solutions

Comment: That's right. I don't expect the reader to be stateless. I am okay with the reader having `StepScope`. However, I don't see a reason why a writer or processor should have `StepScope`. If I understand correctly, you are seeing this is my only option if I want to stick to spring batch 3.0.0?

Comment: or a stateless writer, which references a "dao"-bean (for datatype), which is filled right before the stop (with StepexecutionListener.beforeStep())